# Drupal: Dynamic mass 301 redirecting

Tags: php, drupal, redirect, url-rewriting, seo

We have nearly a hundred thousand paths we need to 301 redirect to a new structure. Something like:

```
 lang.site.com/section/subsection/article
                  -> 
 lang.site.com/newsection/newsubsection/article
```

In the past when migrating from domain.com to newdomain.com we would just put a `.htaccess` file with 10k+ script-generated rows matching old paths to new paths, and it worked okay. It did not affect the performance of the new domain since the `.htaccess` was only read by Apache when a user would try to access the old domain.

This would not work now, since the domain name isn't changing, only the structure of paths. The amount of changing path is nearing the 100 000 mark, so obviously the notion of Apache reading 100 000 lines of `.htaccess` for each pageload is just absurd.

I'd love to have some ideas how to implement this properly, with a low performance-cost. I'm not asking you guys for a ready solution, just some help in brainstorming what would be the most feasible solution in our use case.

We are also going to have a Varnish server in front of Apache serving cached content, but I suppose the following solution would still work, since requests that Varnish can't satisfy are forwarded to the Apache in our LAMP environment.

What I had in mind:

- Drupal 7 has a `html.tpl.php` file which has the `<header>` part of the page
- During execution of `html.tpl.php`, we'd check the MySQL DB to see wether the path requested by the user exists in the new `pathalias` table

  - If path not found and `old path <-> new path` relation was found:

    - PHP `header('Location:');` To 301 redirect the user to the correct new location
  - Else:

    - Let Drupal handle the request as usual and continue execution

We've also been told to update the old domain redirects to directly bring the user to the new site without any 301 chaining. I suppose we could just utilize the same DB check to see if there is a relation between the oldest path to the newest paths via the old path. Luckily we've stored all these even older relations just in case, and now they could be handy.

If you read through, any ideas how to solve this in the best possible manner would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you seen the [Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect)? It integrates with Drupal's page cache for maximum performance and I'm pretty sure you could use it for your purposes. If it doesn't do what you want out of the box it has a good API you can hook into.

Comment: I'm familiar with it, but I am not too keen on using a beta stage module in production environment. I suppose if it was stable, I could populate it's tables with all the path's I need to redirect. Then the old sites should redirect to new site with query parameters and then get forwarded by Redirect module, resulting in 301 chaining.

Comment: Yup that's the way I'd go. Don't know if it eases your concerns but I've been using that module in a bunch of production sites for months now and it's never caused any issues.

Comment: The 301-chaining is unacceptable though, and if I need to create the code to have the long-way relating paths I might as well do it fully with that one solution. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would try

1) The  easy method.

Try the module http://drupal.org/project/pathauto

You can define a pattern for your module.

```
lang.site.com/newsection/newsubsection/article

lang.site.com/[node:newsection]/[term:newsubsection]

// This is an example not the actual pattern u will use. If you can't seem to get this then 
revert back.
```

The path will be created only during a cron job. so you performance will not be affected.

2) The above method should be good enough if not then. You can write a module and implement the below logic

A - hook_cron() // At every cron run the below should run
B - Load the node using node_load()
C- Check the uri of the node to your pattern 
D- If it does not match change it.
E - save the node using node_save()

Cheers,
vishal

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to my question. Next time, read further than 3 lines or don't reply at all, please.